# react-explode library gives "Invalid hook call" error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to use the react-explode library in my react app (made with `yarn create-react-app`). Any use of the library causes my application to fail at runtime, with the following error: `Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call` in the console.

This happens even in the simplest case, with the following `index.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Siargao from "react-explode/Siargao";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Siargao />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using a newer version of React than the `react-explode` supports.

[package.json dependencies](https://github.com/bigfanjs/react-explode/blob/develop/package.json#L30-L31)

> ```
> "dependencies": {
>   "eases": "^1.0.8",
>   "eslint-plugin-babel": "^5.1.0",
>   "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.12.0",
>   "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
>   "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.16.0",
>   "eslint-watch": "^7.0.0",
>   "gsap": "^3.0.4",
>   "react": "^16.11.0",
>   "react-dom": "^16.11.0"
> },
> ```

Using React v16 it works without issue, but with v17 I can reproduce the hook error.

Here's a running codesandbox demo using React 16.14.0

[image: Edit react-explode-library-gives-invalid-hook-call-error]

```
import React, { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Siargao from "react-explode/Siargao";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Siargao repeat={-1} size={300} />
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

[image]

There are [no issues](https://github.com/bigfanjs/react-explode/issues) filed with the project to bump React support. The last update to the repo was 2+ years ago, so it doesn't appear to be in active development.

You can:

1. File the issue to bump support and hope the owner updates.
2. Fork and fix the dependencies yourself and

   1. Maintain your own fork
   2. Open a PR with the repo and hope it gets merged
3. Downgrade your version of React (*`react` and `react-dom`*) to a supported ^16.11.0 version and use.
4. Move on to another package.

Comment: thank you! I had to also downgrade react-dom to the same version and now it works.

Comment: @vonClem Correct. `react` and `react-dom` versions should ***always*** match. Sorry for not also explicitly calling that out. Cheers.